# Converting Objective-C malloc to Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am working on a project that was written in Objective-C and needs to be updated to Swift. We use a C file for transferring data.

Here is the code I was given in Objective-C:

```
- (NSData *)prepareEndPacket {
    UInt8 *buff_data;
    buff_data = (uint8_t *)malloc(sizeof(uint8_t)*(PACKET_SIZE+5));
    // Call to C File
    PrepareEndPacket(buff_data);
    NSData *data_first = [NSData dataWithBytes:buff_data length:sizeof(uint8_t)*(PACKET_SIZE+5)];
    return data_first;
}
```

In the C .h file I have this for reference:

```
#define PACKET_SIZE     ((uint32_t)128)
```

I can not seem to find a good way of converting this to Swift. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That code will leak the malloc'ed data. It should be using `dataWithBytesNoCopy` to create the `NSData` object instead of `dataWithBytes` so that the `NSData` object takes ownership of the `malloc`'ed data buffer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`malloc` and `free` actually work fine in Swift; however, the `UnsafeMutablePointer` API is more "native". I'd probably use `Data`'s `bytesNoCopy` for better performance. If you want, you can use `Data(bytes:count:)`, but that will make a copy of the data (and then you need to make sure to deallocate the pointer after making the copy, or you'll leak memory, which is actually a problem in the Objective-C code above since it fails to `free` the buffer).

So, something like:

```
func prepareEndPacket() -> Data {
    let count = PACKET_SIZE + 5
    let buf = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: count)

    PrepareEndPacket(buf)

    return Data(bytesNoCopy: buf, count: count, deallocator: .custom { ptr, _ in
        ptr.deallocate()
    })
}
```

By using `bytesNoCopy`, the `Data` object returned is basically a wrapper around the original pointer, which will be freed by the deallocator when the `Data` object is destroyed.

Alternatively, you can create the `Data` object from scratch and get a pointer to its contents to pass to `PrepareEndPacket()`:

```
func prepareEndPacket() -> Data {
    var data = Data(count: PACKET_SIZE + 5)

    data.withUnsafeMutableBytes { (ptr: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>) in
        PrepareEndPacket(ptr)
    }

    return data
}
```

This is *slightly* less efficient, since the `Data(count:)` initializer will initialize all the `Data`'s bytes to zero (similar to using `calloc` instead of `malloc`), but in many cases, that may not make enough of a difference to matter.

Comment: Excellent answer (voted). You might want to expand on why the Objective-C code leaks.

Comment: @Charles Srstka I have one other section that I may need help on. It uses memcpy

Comment: @temp_ Post a new question and I'll have a look at it.